# Error while installing npm packages npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: bash, npm, npm-install, npm-start

Don't know what happened but I receive the following error while

```
>npx create-react-app .
>npm i <packages>
>npm install
```

and so on, so none of the commands above work

the error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! file C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! core-js@2.6.11 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.11 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've seen that it's mostly Windows problem but I work with Mac

Answer (score 6):

Open CMD as administrator and then run:

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8441 this might help you. Might be because of the wrong bash!